# Mi textura no se muestra en SDL

Tags: c++

Lo que ocurre es que defino código para mostrar una parte de textura en C++ con las librerías SDL. Algo así:

```
 #include <SDL.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

SDL_Window * ventana;
SDL_Renderer * render;
SDL_Texture * textura;

SDL_Rect tRect1, tRectD1; // Uno selecciona el área de la textura y el otro dónde se va a mostrar.

int main()
{
    // ... omitimos la inicialización, crear ventana, contexto y establecer color
    while(!salir) // Variable que cuando se vuelva verdad saldrá del bucle 
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&evento)){
            // Insertense los eventos que quiera...
        }

        SDL_RenderClear() // Limpia la pantalla
        SDL_RenderCopy(render, textura, &tRect1, &tRectD1); // Función de render
        SDL_RenderPresent() // Actualiza la pantalla
    }
    // Insertese código de cierre
    return 0;
}
```

El problema surge al momento de inicializar las estructuras rect "tRect1" y "tRectD1"; si los inicializo fuera del while principal -while(!salir)-, la imagen no se muestra, pero, al inicializarlos dentro del bucle, si lo muestra. ¿Alguien sabe por qué y cómo puedo resolverlo?

Gracias
Quedo atento a cualquier sugerencia.